# #! en url de angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

hice una aplicacion con angularjs, en el ngroute tengo

```js
var appLogin = angular.module('appLogin', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource'])

// Declared route 
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  // alert(JSON.stringify($routeProvider));
  $routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'views/loginView.aspx',
    controller: 'loginController'
  })




}]);
```

El tema es que al ejecutarlo me direcciona a `http://localhost:51384/login.html#!/`

¿Alguien podría explicarme qué es el `!`? Entiendo que el `#` es porque a partir de ahí van los parámetros para la navegación, pero ¿qué es `!`? ¿se puede quitar?

En PHP sólo me generaba el `#`, gracias

Comment: ¿Te aparece algún error en la consola?

Comment: El ! está relacionado al modo Hashbang, AngularJS lo para deep linking. Podés ver un poco mas en esta respuesta http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40478676/i-am-using-angular-and-my-url-always-has-a-exclamation-mark

Comment: buenisimo, lo resolvi con 
.config(['$locationProvider', function ($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
}]);
habia estado dos dias pensando que era algun espacio o algo raro por algun lado. jaja, muchas gracias

Answer (score 4):

Lo que estas viendo **`#!`** se conoce como hashbang y es una invención de los ingenieros de google para ayudar al buscador a reconocer que páginas debe indexar. Según los comentarios veo que lo has desabilitado, mi recomendación es que lo actives ya que tenerlo desabilitado no trae ningún beneficio para tu sitio.

Lee https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/learn-more

Si lo que no te gusta es como se ve la url puedes activar el modo html5 pero eso implica que debes configurar el servidor que estés usando para trabajar en ese modo. Puedes encontrar dicha configuración con una rápida búsqueda de Google ya que para cada tipo de servidor (IIS, apache, node, etc...) los pasos a seguir son diferentes.

En tu aplicación siempre debes escribir la configuración

```js
angular.module('myModule')
  .config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
      $locationProvider.html5Mode(true)
  }
]);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, voy a hacer lo que comentas al principio,lo voy a dejar, ya que primeramente pensaba que era un problema de url, de charset o algo parecido, muchas gracias

Comment: Hola, como va, lo deje activado como decis, y tengo #! en las url, el problema es que al querer compartir en face o whatsapp la url http://misitio.com.ar/sucursal/web/#!/44
Solo me comparte http://misitio.com.ar/sucursal/web/
Como que no le gusta #!
Probe con $locationProvider.html5Mode(true)
y haciendo un encode url con javascript y no me funciona tampoco, que puedo hacer?
muchas gracias